# Identify significant features in clustering results

Tags: clustering, interpretation

I'm a student in Data Analysis, working on a data clustering exercise.

Two clusters have been identified based on a dataset with 40 features. To interpret and label these clusters, I'm wondering if there is a way to determine which features are the most determinant in the clustering output. For instance, I would imagine that I could take out one feature from the clustering and see how much it affects the output. However there are probably smarter ways.

I would greatly appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar [post appears on Cross-Validated, "Estimating the most important features in a k-means cluster partition"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77689/estimating-the-most-important-features-in-a-k-means-cluster-partition).

Quoting from that post:

> One way to quantify the usefulness of each feature (= variable =
> dimension), from the book [Burns, Robert P., and Richard Burns.
> Business research methods and statistics using SPSS. Sage, 2008.](http://www.uk.sagepub.com/burns/website%20material/Chapter%2023%20-%20Cluster%20Analysis.pdf)
> ([mirror](http://www.scribd.com/doc/88429552/Chapter-23-Cluster-Analysis)), usefulness being defined by the features'
> discriminative power to tell clusters apart.
>
> > We usually examine the means for each cluster on each dimension using
> > ANOVA to assess how distinct our clusters are. Ideally, we would
> > obtain significantly different means for most, if not all dimensions,
> > used in the analysis. The magnitude of the F values performed on each
> > dimension is an indication of how well the respective dimension
> > discriminates between clusters.
>
> Another way would be to remove a specific feature and see how this
> impact [internal quality indices](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/76095/12359). Unlike the first solution, you
> would have to redo the clustering for each feature (or set of
> features) you want to analyze.
>
> FYI:
>
> - [Can a useless feature negatively impact the clustering?](https://www.quora.com/Clustering-statistical-analysis/Can-a-useless-feature-negatively-impact-the-clustering/answer/Franck-Dernoncourt)
> - [Can the choice of the measurement units of the features impact the clustering?](https://www.quora.com/Clustering-statistical-analysis/Can-the-choice-of-the-measurement-units-of-the-features-impact-the-clustering/answer/Franck-Dernoncourt)
> - [Why vector normalization can improve the accuracy of clustering and classification?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15779107/395857)
> - [What are the most commonly used ways to perform feature selection for k-means clustering?](https://www.quora.com/K-Means-Algorithms/What-are-the-most-commonly-used-ways-to-perform-feature-selection-for-k-means-clustering)

Furthermore, there is a paper on [Feature Selection in Clustering Problems](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/7d57/df0e3e2c3ab54642405b32dad8343f9954c5.pdf)

> A novel approach to combining clustering and feature selection is
> presented.   It  implements  a wrapper strategy  for  feature
> selection,  in  the sense that the features are directly selected by
> optimizing the discriminative power of the used partitioning
> algorithm.  On the technical side, we present  an  efficient
> optimization  algorithm  with  guaranteed  local  convergence
> property.  The only free parameter of this method is selected by a
> resampling-based stability analysis.  Experiments with real-world
> datasets demonstrate that our method is able to infer both meaningful
> partitions and meaningful subsets of features.